# How do you escape braces {{var}} in a polymer template?

Tags: polymer

How do you escape curly braces in a Polymer template? I've seen both of these as suggestions but they both throw "Invalid expression syntax" errors.

1. {{ '{{' }}var{{ '}}' }}
2. {{ '{{var}}' }}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `{{'\{{var}\}'}}`? Seems to work.

Comment: I was a bit dissapointed that it also didn't work to just encode the brackets/braces as HTML entities like `[[foo]]` → `&#91;&#91;foo&#93;&#93;`. Polymer still tries to parse it as a data binding.

Answer (score 1):

To escape things like `{{..asdf..}}` or `[[..asdf..]]` in regular HTML code in the template use `&shy;` in between: `{&shy;{..whatever..}&shy;}`

Comment: Interesting idea, but this doesn't really work good if the escaped code is part of a visible code example (or something similar) as people may want to copy the example from the page but then they will end up with the extra non-printable characters and the copied code doesn't work as intended.