# Character escaping in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm creating a component with Polymer which has a background image added with inline styles. The problem is that using double brackets inside parenthesis and quotes makes the {{imageurl}} act like a string. Any tips?

```
<div class="image-container" style="background-image: url( '{{imageurl}}' )">
```

Update: I've tried the method [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966597/how-do-you-escape-braces-var-in-a-polymer-template) with no luck.

Comment: Which version of Polymer are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will have to do is have a computed property that returns the style:

```
<div style$="{{divStyle}}">hi</div>
```

Note the use of `$=` here as were are data-binding to an `attribute`. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding) for more info.

And your JavaScript:

```
Polymer({
  is: "test-element",
  properties: {
    backgroundColor: {
      type: String,
      value: '#FF0000'
    },
    divStyle: {
      computed: 'getDivStyle(backgroundColor)'
    }
  },
  getDivStyle: function(backgroundColor) {
    return 'background-color: ' + backgroundColor + ';';
  }
});
```

See [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/kyOcZAWsxTasBshDJmb8?p=preview) plunker to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

String interpolation is not yet supported in Polymer 1.0. Use [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) instead.

```
<!-- Notice the `$` sign. Use attribute binding (`$=`) when binding native elements attribute -->
<div style$="{{_computeBackgroundImage(imageurl)}}"></div>


Polymer({
    ...
    _computeBackgroundImage: function(url) {
        return 'background-image: url('+url+');';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you use computed bindings to solve this?

Comment: Edited my comment to answer your question.