# Polymer V.1 how to concatenate some text to iron-list item that has json data e.g text{{data.somedata}}text

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm Using iron-ajax with iron-list and for the iron-image i need to concatenate text to the image source that has`{{item.path}}`

i tried this way

```
<iron-image style="width:80px; height:80px;" sizing="cover" src="http://mydomain/{{item.path}}.jpg" preload></iron-image>
```

But i get no image loaded and upon inspecting a list item it doesn't insert the path of the image coming from json data.

```
src="http://mydomain/{{item.path}}.jpg"
```

What is the way to concatenate the above

by itself `src="{{item.path}}"` i see the path when i inspect an item

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String interpolation is not yet supported in Polymer 1.0. You will need to use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed).

For instance:

```
<dom-module id="your-tag">
  <template>
     <iron-image 
      style="width:80px; height:80px;"
      sizing="cover"
      src$="{{_getImagePath(item.path)}}"
      preload></iron-image>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "your-tag",
      _getImagePath: function(url) {
        return 'http://mydomain/' + url + '.jpg';
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448084/character-escaping-in-polymer/31449809#31449809).

Comment: Thanks, its working :) ok i sort of understand now, it cleared things up

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to declare item.path

you should 
Polymer({ item.path: "/set/your/path"});

Comment: its json data so i get the path ok. if i just have src="{{item.path}}" i see the path. its when i have src="http://mydomain/{{item.path}}.jpg" i dont see the path. do you know how to join text with {{data.data}} ??

Answer (score 0):

i think this example may solve you problem:

```
function(myPath) {
    return 'http://mydomain/' + myPath + ".jpg";
}
```

then you can use in the following way:

```
src="http://mydomain/{{myPath(item.path)}}"
```

you may also look [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1770) for further investigation and more comprehensive examples.