# Polymer Need some help building a url in iron-list item

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm running into a similar problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516990/polymer-v-1-how-to-concatenate-some-text-to-iron-list-item-that-has-json-data-e).

However, my case is a bit different and I can't seem to get it to work. I've been playing with it for a while an no luck so far.. I need `href$="{{_getProject(item.project_id)}}"` to be written as `"webservices/api/projects/1"` but the closest thing I can get is it outputting the `item.project_id` without being able to concatenate with it so just the 1.  I've tried various things but below is what I have most recently. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work? I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking.

```
<template is="dom-bind">
    <iron-ajax url="<?echo $url?>" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax>
    <iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
        <template>
            <div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad">
                       <div class="primary">[[item.project_name]]</div>
                       <div class="secondary">Project Deadline:</div> 
                       <div class="secondary">[[item.project_deadline]</div
                       <div class="secondary">Total Hours to date:</div>
                       <div class="secondary">[[item.project_total_hours</div>
                       <div class="secondary">[[item.project_id]]</div>
                    </div>
                    <a  href$="{{_getProject(item.project_id)}}"><iron-icon icon="assignment"><iron-icon></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
              _getProject: function(url) {
                return 'webservices/api/projects/' + url
             }
           });
       </script>
    </iron-list>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Polymer({...})` call you have inside of your iron-list won't work as you expect (and it should actually show an error in the console), since you are not defining/can't define a custom element inside of `iron-list` but only a template that will be stamped.

There are two ways to achieve what you want.

1. Define a custom element that you use inside of the `iron-list`

   ```
   <dom-module id="my-item">
     <template>
       <div class="item">
         ...
         <a  href$="{{_getProject(item.project_id)}}">...</a>
       </div>
     </template>
     <script>
       Polymer({
         is: 'my-item',
         properties: {
           item: Object
         },
         _getProject: function(url) {
           return 'webservices/api/projects/' + url
         }
       });
     </script>
   </dom-module>


   <iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
     <template>
       <my-item item="[[item]]"></my-item>
     </template>
   </iron-list>
   ```
2. Define the `_getProject` function on your main template

   ```
   <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
     ...
     <iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
       <template>
         <div>
           <div class="item">
             ...
             <a href$="{{_getProject(item.project_id)}}">...</a>
           </div>
         </div>
       </template>
     </iron-list>
   </template>

   <script>
     var app = document.getElementById('app');
     app._getProject = function (url) {
       return 'webservices/api/projects/' + url
     }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thank you sir. That actually explains it much better for me.  I had tried wrapping a dom module around my whole template/iron list(which I see now was totally wrong as well). I used your method 2 and it worked as intended. but method 1 makes a lot more sense to me now as well.  Thank you again